# What is the token validity time when using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are actually using GRAPH API to access active directory users and groups from a Jira script.
For that we use the so called "no user authentication" by using Secret Key and Client key after registering an application on Azure AD.

We undertand the following points

1. Before sending any POST request to Graph API we need to get a valid Token.
2. The token value is associated to permission in place
3. If we change the permission, we need to get a new token to include the change

Our question is as below:

1. First can you confirm that we we state above is correct ?
2. Does it means that before each request we need to request the token each time to be sure it is valid ?
3. Is tehre any expiration of a token which is send with each request ?

Thanks for those clarification
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you acquire an access token, the response contains the expiration time.
By default it is one hour.

You only need to get a new token if the one you have has expired/is going to expire soon.

Comment: do you have any idea if this Graph API can be used in production or is it still a preview state ? what happen if by mistake MS decide to change endpoint API, do the keep old version ? I am aware of less maintenance as possible

Comment: MS Graph API v1.0 is fully production supported. The beta version is not.

Comment: in case a new api version is available, does previous is still existing usually ?

Comment: Well, there hasn't yet been a new version :D it's been only v1.0 for quite some time. But considering the massive number of applications using the API, avoiding breaking changes is pretty important for them.